# Is there any alternative of `document.getElementById('first')` in typescript?

Tags: angular

As per my knowledge `document.getElementById('first')` is used in JavaScript. and I want to know if there is any other way to access a particular div with it's id in Typescript for Angular-8. Kindly let me know, It would be very helpful for me.

Comment: TypeScript is just another language. It doesn't come with any additional DOM API. And regarding Angular, you should most probably not find elements by ID in Angular code: it's probably a sign that you're using the framework the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `@ViewChild()` to refer template elements in typescript.**

**In your template HTML:**

```html
<div #MyDiv>Hello World</div>
```

**In your component.ts:**

```js
@ViewChild("MyDiv") div: ElementRef;

changeContent() {
  this.div.nativeElement.innerHTML = "text";
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works with `id`, he should use template reference variable instead (e.g. query `<my-component #first></my-component>` with `@ViewChild('first')`).

Comment: For Angular 8: `@ViewChild('first', {static: false})`

Comment: You can user ngModel  <input [(ngModel)]="name" #ctrl="ngModel" required> more on https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: Thank you C_Ogoo , SelakaN and @uminder . I will try that.

Comment: Does the local storage item is still there once you refresh?